# discord py on_reaction_remove() doesnt work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot using python, I have completed everything I wanted so far, but I cant seem to fix this 1 problem: on_reaction_remove just doesnt seem to work for me.
Code snippet:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
  print('removed')
```

Also I did try setting up my intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

and enabled all the Privileged Gateway Intents on the developer portal.

I have read most of the answers on google/stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work for me...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)`? `on_reaction_remove` only triggers for messages that are already in the bot's internal cache, so if the message was not found then it will never be called. the `raw` variant is always called but has different parameters.

Comment: Any errors or something or is it just silently not working?